# I want to disable 2nd column when 1 st row is inserted in a kendo grid, not after that

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo ui grid with toolbar create.

In that, I want to disable 2nd column when 1st row is inserted.
From 2nd row onwards, I want that column to be enabled.
I Also want to insert count in 1st column on every insert in the grid.

For example: If the first row is inserted, I want 1st column to be "Tier 1".
If 2nd row is inserted, then I want 1st column to be as "Tier 2".
If out of 3, 2nd row is deleted... I want the 3rd row 1st column to be converted from "Tier 3" to "Tier 2".

Can someone please help me achieve this?
I am struggling to have this much of control in kendo grid.
Here is the code below:

```
 var rateScheduleItemGridDatasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            type: 'get',
            url: config.apiServer + "api/RateSchedule/GetAllRateScheduleItems?rateScheduleId=" + selectedRateScheduleId,
            dataType: "json"
        },
        destroy: {
            type: 'delete',
            url: function (options) {
                alert('hi');
                $.ajax({
                    url: config.apiServer + "api/RateSchedule/DeleteRateScheduleItem?rateScheduleItemId=" + options.RateScheduleItemId,
                    type: 'delete',
                    data: ko.toJSON(options),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        popupNotification.show(updateSuccessMessage, "success");
                        rateScheduleItemGridDatasource.read();
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        popupNotification.show(updateFailureMessage, "error");
                    }
                });
            },
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json"
        }
    },
    serverPaging: false,
    serverSorting: false,
    serverFiltering: false,
    serverGrouping: false,
    serverAggregates: false,
    batch: true,
    schema: {
        data: "Data",
        total: "Total",
        errors: "Errors",
        model: {
            id: "RateScheduleItemId",
            fields: {
                RateScheduleItemId: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: false },
                RateScheduleId: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                MathmetricalSymbolCode: { type: "number", nullable: true, editable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                MathmetricalSymbolCodeValue: { type: "string", nullable: true, editable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                MeasureTypeCode: { type: "number", nullable: true, editable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                MeasureTypeCodeValue: { type: "string", nullable: true, editable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                MultiplierRate: { type: "number", nullable: true, editable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                RangeLowerNumber: { type: "number", nullable: true, editable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                RangeUpperNumber: { type: "number", nullable: true, editable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                RateTier: { type: "string", nullable: true, editable: false, validation: { required: false } }
            }
        }
    }
});
 $("#rateScheduleItemGrid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
        { "command": [{ name: "destroy", text: "&nbsp" }], "width": "60px" },
        { "title": "Rate Tier", "width": "100px", "field": "RateTier" },
        { "title": "Operand", "width": "100px", "field": "MathmetricalSymbolCodeValue", "editor": rateScheduleItemOperandDropDownEditor, values: rateScheduleItemOperandReferenceData },
        { "title": "Range (From)", "width": "100px", "field": "RangeLowerNumber" },
        { "title": "Range (to)", "width": "100px", "field": "RangeUpperNumber" },
        { "title": "Rate (Multiplier)", "width": "100px", "field": "MultiplierRate" }
    ],
    resizable: true,
    editable: true,
    editable: {
        createAt: "bottom"
    },
    groupable: false,
    filterable: false,
    pageable: false,
    sortable: false,
    scrollable: true,
    height: 200,
    dataSource: rateScheduleItemGridDatasource,
    cancel: function (e) {
        dirty = false;
    },
    save: function (e) {
        dirty = false;
    }
});
```

With below code, I have a separate button on click of which I am adding a new row in the grid.
I am not using Kendo ui grid Built in Toolbar feature.

```
 $('#AddAnotherTier').click(function () {
    if (selectedRateScheduleId === 0) {
        var grid = $("#rateScheduleItemGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.addRow();
        if (grid.dataSource.total() == 1) {
            //To do - make the operand column disabled
        }
    }
});
```

And RateTier will be the 1st column which I want to update its text on client side as per the row inserted 1 by 1.

Comment: Please provide a code for us in jsfiddle/plnkr.

Comment: Addded code in the question itself, please have a look. Thanks.